# Arrayformula in Sheets for autofilling with Trend formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, trend, textjoin

I have a Trend formula that takes a small horizontal array as an input and I want it to autofill a column using arrayformula.  If the y and x ranges for Trend are A_:C_ and D_:F_, I can't say A2:C and D2:F because it will take in the full column as the trend array.  I tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TREND(OFFSET(A1:C1,ROW(A2:A)-1,0),OFFSET(D1:F1,ROW(A2:A)-1,0),1,False))
```

but the ROW(A2:A) doesn't make arrayformula reprint in each cell of the column; only the first cell fills.  Is there a way to make it autopopulate despite the arguments being horizontal arrays?

view the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M9DMhcc8r7ngKgjN4OuhNh1wVGocQGMz1go-LZEWquw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet (the one that you *can* see and were able to reference as you wrote your post). We don't know your spreadsheet layout, data, data types or what the end results should look like. So we have no foundation from which to understand your post. Please share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a sample spreadsheet) with enough realistic data entered to fully represent the problem and your hand-entered results of what you would like a formula to produce, where you would like the formula to produce it.

Comment: @ErikTyler, good call.  Just updated the post

Comment: Is the sample data in the spreadsheet you linked to realistic? For instance, are your Col-A values all really going to be 2 to the power of 0,1,2,3..., with Col-B and Col-C data being 2x and 3x those Col-A values each time? And will the Col-D, Col-E and Col-F values always be constant as shown? I don't think TREND works with an array because the function itself is already an array function. However, if there is some regular relationship between the numbers, there may be another way to get the same results with an array. Google doesn't recommend using TREND with fewer than 10 data points.

Comment: @ErikTyler unfortunately there is not a pattern between rows of data.  3 data points is standard and the slope value it provides has always worked well for our purposes.

Comment: I recommend that you change your data to be more of a *realistic* representation of your real data. Any of the volunteer contributors who look at your data will see the same pattern I did unless you change the data to remove the appearance of a pattern. In addition, you used the word "slope" above. But TREND doesn't appear to deliver the simple slope of a line. If it *does*, then slope has a formula, and that formula may be able to be used to create an array formula longhand.

Comment: @ErikTyler, TREND with a [b] value of FALSE returns only the m value as b is forced to be 0.  m is obviously the slope in mx+b.  I would be interested in the longhand formula for a best fit line with a forced 0 y-intercept.

Comment: The sample data you entered has a clear slope that can be figured in one's head at a glance for each line (e.g., the slope for row 2 data is 2, the slope for row 3 data is 4, etc. (which are not terribly close to the TREND results you get for the same). Do keep in mind that we don't know what your big-picture goal is. And this is a Google Sheets forum not necessarily a math forum (Stack has a math forum if that is what you need). But as I happen to be good with math, I can see that all your sample data has a regular slope without scatter. Again, feel free to share more realistic data.

Comment: @ErikTyler the forced 0 y-intercept is critical.  Some quickly-chosen sample numbers with an easy to spot, non-zero intercept slope is irrelevant.

Comment: I am not understanding your full goal, then, Matthew. And that is not surprising: everyone has a tendency to feel that a topic we deal with day in and day out is clear to everyone else. That said, I don't think I can take you any further with this particular issue, as I do not understand that goal yet and don't think it will be an efficient use of the limited time I can donate here (about 45 minutes per week total). If you can direct me to some underlying long-form formula that gives the result you want, I may look again. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TREND is already arrayformula type of function so the functionality you seek is not possible. but...

it can be achieved like this by hardcoding it:

```
={TREND(A2:C2, D2:F2, 1, );
  TREND(A3:C3, D3:F3, 1, );
  TREND(A4:C4, D4:F4, 1, );
  TREND(A5:C5, D5:F5, 1, )}
```

[image]

ofc if you cant say how many rows you will have or you dont want to type in 50 rows by hand you can use formula which will generate a formula like this:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA("={"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, "TREND(A"&
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A), 1, ROW(A2))&":C"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A), 1, ROW(A2))&", D"&
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A), 1, ROW(A2))&":F"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A), 1, ROW(A2))&", 1, 0)")&"}")}
```

and then you just copy-paste generated fx from bellow:

[image]